# Rerender a command button

Tags: salesforce

I need to Rerender a command button on my VF page on saving the page.

Right now, I have 3 buttons on my VF page, Save, Test, Cancel.

I want that when the user opens this VF page, on button click in contact object, on this Vf page, initially the user should only see the Save & Cancel buttons. Once the user clicks on the Save button, then the Test button should appear.

Any thoughts how this can be done? The save and cancel buttons have the standard salesforce save & cancel function.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the button, i would do it with jQuery:

```salesforce
<apex:commantButton action="{!save}" id="saveButton" reRender="something" oncomplete="showTest()"/>

<apex:commantButton action="{!test}" id="testButton" style="display:none;/>
```

```js
function showTest(){
    jQuery("[id$=testButton]").css("display","block");
}
```